# Missing embedded stylesheets in production after compile (error 404)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

In my local machine, my embedded stylesheets show up fine. When deployed to production, those embedded stylesheets are missing and see 404's in Firebug. This is strange because I have deployed to this production machine before and the embedded stylesheets were fine.

I did a clean and rebuild, but no luck. It is an ASP.NET 3.5 Solution if that helps. Any ideas on why this could be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you're publishing your application to production, you might want to check to make sure that the .css file's build property is set to `Content`.

If you are doing a "publish", this will cause files added with the incorrect build action to be excluded from the final output. I usually see this with automated build/deployment servers.

Comment: I ended doing a Windows update and rebooted. That got rid of the strange problem. Maybe was maxing my CPU or something.